# How to set up Loki Render on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: network, performance

I am trying to do network rendering in Blender3D using [Loki Render](http://loki-render.berlios.de/) across my 3 Xserves. I have no experience in setting up network rendering and the instructions that are given on the Loki Render home page do not help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the documentation page on the Loki Render site? It seems pretty straightforward. Do you have any more-specific questions about how to do various parts of the setup?

Comment: I don't know just how to explain it. I am not knowing how to get the master computer to recognize the grunts. I have enabled file sharing on all my machines so I can see them on my network. So when I try to set up the xserves as grunts it comes up with this window and I don't know what I should select.

Comment: How do I add a screenshot in the comment of the window that I am trying to show.

Comment: Honestly, I've never figured out how to upload screenshots to Stack Exchange. @bmike can you help with this?

Comment: Just post a link to the screen shot and one of us can edit it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loki render passes files around internally, so you don't need to set up any type of file sharing, whether it be Mac, Windows or Linux. Just make sure your computers can ping each other, and Loki's grunts *should* be able to connect to the master no problems. If you still have trouble, check firewall settings.